# What does the phrase "dropped loot" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "dropped loot" in the following sentence from the description of the game "Teamfight Tactics":

> While your warriors automatically clash, you’ll manually guide your
>   adorable Little Legend captain to scoop up **dropped loot**.
>   ([source](https://apps.apple.com/gb/story/a-truly-explosive-platformer/id1502297787))

I have found the phrase "dropped loot" in many games, but I am not sure about its meaning. I know the lexical meanings of the word "loot" are "goods stolen during pillaging" and "a collection of valued items". I am not sure which of the meanings fits here.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In many games, when you defeat a bad guy, they leave loot behind for you to benefit from. We say they "dropped" the loot for you to collect.

Answer (score 1):

"Dropped loot" can only mean *loot* that has been *dropped*.

"Loot" means a stash of money, usually money that has been stolen.

"Dropped" means left behind, usually by accident.

Answer (score 0):

"Dropping" is a gamer euphemism for dying while carrying something. So "The monster dropped a bag of gold" means the monster died and the bag of gold is available to be taken.

In this case "loot" mostly means "a collection of valued items". It could also mean "goods stolen during pillaging" if you're willing to accept that your warriors are pillaging.